# How can I show that $AX=AY$?

Tags: geometry, circles

In the diagram below, the two circles have equal radii. However after much bashing around with angles, I was not able to show that $AX=AY$.

My only idea so far is to try to instead prove that $\angle AXY = \angle AYX$, yet I was still unable to do this. We of course need to incorporate the fact that both circles have equal radii at some point, but I cannot see a way of doing this without lots of constructions and tedious angle chasing.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The small arcs $AX$ of the left circle and $AY$ of the right circle both span the same angle $\angle ABY$.

Comment: This is (almost)  merely stating the result that was to be proven. How do you justify that they span the same angle? IN the right circle I see that the span is arc ABY, but Y is not even in the left circle.

Comment: Two arcs are equal iff they subtend the same angle. Since both of these arcs subtended the same angle (yes they are different circles, but as the circles are identical then they may as well be in the same circle), then the arcs must be equal and thus the chords are equal.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

As figure shows, $\angle AZB+\angle AYB=180^\circ.$ Moreover, since
the two circle have the same size, by using the property of the inscribed angles, $\angle AZB=\angle AXB$.
Therefore $\angle AXB+\angle AYB=180^\circ,$ that is, $\angle AXY=\angle AYX.$
Hence $AX=AY.$

Comment: Don't see how the figure shows $\angle AZB + \angle AYB = 180^\circ$.

Comment: Because $AZBY$ is the cyclic quadrilateral, so its opposite angles are supplementary.

Answer (score 1):

If the center on the left is $O_1$ and on the right is $O_2$, then 
$$
\angle ABY=0.5 \angle AO_1X = 0.5 \angle AO_2Y
$$